# SwiftUI: resize View to the content size

Tags: view, size, swiftui

1. I have some large view full of some sort of subViews
2. I don't know which size of content of the view

How to:

1. Automatically resize view to it's content
2. Set maxSize of window? (If content is larger than this size, window must will have this size, but not content size.)

---

At the moment I think about following direction:

1. Wrap it with frame

   ```
   .frame(minWidth: 450, idealWidth: 1000, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 250, idealHeight: 1000, maxHeight: .infinity)
   ```
2. to use GeometryReader go get parent size

but I don't know how to do this correctly

Comment: Don't use .frame view modifier and don't use Spacer() or GeometryReader internally  (which consume all available space by default), and, as a result, all will be tight to its content automatically.

Comment: @Asperi it is not solution because of it's impossible to set horizontalAligment to HStack. So it's impossible to do not use `Spacer()` at all. =(

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm stuck with the same problem. The View shrinks to the minimum of the direct content, and doesn't size based on the child contents. Seems like an obvious thing and I can't get it working :(